# Capture keystroke without focus in console

Tags: c#, events, console, key

I know there is a question for Windows Forms but it doesn't work in the console, or at least I couldn't get it to work. I need to capture key presses even though the console doesn't have focus.

Comment: @saluce: There are plenty of legitimate reasons for global keyboard hooks (as well as of course illegitimate ones).

Comment: @saluce im making a program so i can run code when i enter certain key combonations

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a global keyboard hook in a console application, too.

Here's complete, working code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c

You create a *console application*, but must add a reference to *System.Windows.Forms* for this to work.  There's no reason a console app can't reference that dll.

I just created a console app using this code and verified that it gets each key pressed, whether or not the console app has the focus.

**EDIT**

The main thread will run Application.Run() until the application exits, e.g. via a call to Application.Exit().  The simplest way to do other work is to start a new Task to perform that work.  Here's a modified version of Main() from the linked code that does this

```
public static void Main()
{
    var doWork = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Application.Exit(); // Quick exit for demonstration only.  
        });

    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

    Application.Run();

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
}
```

**NOTE**

Possibly provide a means to exit the Console app, e.g. when a special key combo is pressed depending on your specific needs.  In the

Comment: Why the downvote?  It answers the question and is verified to work.

Comment: The application gets stuck on the Application.Run() line. how can i integrate this functionality into an existing console app without making it wait for key strokes?

Comment: @EricJ. just to clarify that just preventing the Main from returning won't work. A call to `Application.Run()` is needed

Comment: @fabriciorissetto: You're right, that edit was an error.  I fixed it.

Comment: Spent so much time figuring out why it is not working in console app, added `Application.Run()` and finally went to sleep. Although, don't know why in WPF app it is not working.. Event is called only once.

Comment: This does work when you are using Notepad or MS Word but is does not work when I type into Visual Studio or Notepad++. Does anyone know how to make it work in either Visual Studio or Notepad++?

Comment: Where's the rest of the last sentence?

Comment: If anyone else is stupidly bad at everything in C# and not 100% sure why you're doing this in the first place and are getting an error that Application does not exist.... In the solution explorer, there's a thing titled references. Right click it, click add reference, and select System.Windows.Forms in the list.