# how to detect button presses without being selected on the program

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a C# program that detects inactivity, and I was trying to do this by checking the keyboard buttons, but `Console.ReadLine()` can only detect keyboard inputs if they happen while in the window, how would I make it read the keyboard input without being inside the window.

Comment: What kind of program are you creating? WinForms, WPF, Xamarin?

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but my guess is you could create a Timer that is triggered every so many milliseconds. And add a Control.KeyPress event (in WinForms). If a key is pressed set a flag and test that flag in the Timer callback. In the Timer callback count the number of iterations without a key being pressed.You need to be aware that a Timer in fact uses Threading so your flag must be handled in a Thread safe manner using lock() or a Mutex and volatile variables. Read up on Threading before you attempt this.

Comment: @PaulSinnema I believe this is for a console application as he referenced `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: @shrek231 Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411887/how-to-send-keys-data-to-a-console-window-without-having-focus) answer your question?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os) may answer your question.

Comment: @Hayden that did answer my question, but how do i close the question now that its answered? im new to stackoverflow