# Capture keyboard strokes with timing C#

Tags: c#

First of all, my question is not for malicious intents, it is for research purposes. Is it possible to get each keyboard stroke and record how much each stroke took? (For example: 120 ms for "A", and so on)
Is there any event in C# or a library that helps me recording each character stroke on the keyboard? 
Thank you

Comment: Linked question has a full solution in one of the answers.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve my issue. I want to record timing for each pressed key on the keyboard, or does it ?

Comment: The [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988197/capture-keystroke-without-focus-in-console) completely covers what the post is asking. If you really having problem with something else (like how to log information or how to find information on Windows events) please either clarify your question OR ask new one.

Comment: No, it doesn't fully solve it, but SO isn't here to provide complete working solutions to tasks - it's here to solve specific issues. The MSDN article will get you into a working solution which logs keys. Look into `HookCallback` - you're given the type of event in `wParam`.. of which you're interested in `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`. From here, you should be able to modify it a bit to figure out the time difference. If not, there are plenty of questions regarding timing in `C#`, and if you're *still* stuck, create a new post regarding what you're specifically stuck on