# C# - Passively checking for key press

Tags: c#, keypress

**I am not using windows forms so this is not a duplicate of [Capture keystroke without focus in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988197/capture-keystroke-without-focus-in-console). Please remove the duplicate label or direct me somewhere else**

So have been away from C# for a long time and trying to get back into it. I am messing with a small console app that requires inputting text from the user. The whole program works fine but now I want to add a check to see if escape is ever pressed.

I originally used ReadKey, but that just checks the current key which has two problems.
1. it uses the key pressed, so strings are missing a character (the one which was checked)
2. it is only in the moment. I want it to be passively waiting until its pressed

What would be the best way to do this?

ex:

I type the string "Hello World!"
If I press the desired key(lets say escape) at any time, I want it to react. Otherwise the string should be entered like normal

*edit*
example of made up dictionary program (yes, I know there is already a class for this)

```
while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
            string entry = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!entry.Contains(","))
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
}
```

Thank you all very much for your time.

Comment: Please provide some sample code of what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: So you want to asynchronously react to a key press event in a console app? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're getting at but you can use this to detect if the Escape key was pressed.

```
 if (Console.KeyAvailable) 
        if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        { 
          // Do something
        }
    }
```

Or alternatively use a loop that breaks when Escape is entered:

```
var x = Console.ReadKey();
while (x.Key.ToString() != "Escape")
    x = Console.ReadKey();
```